# CSS tags inside JSON

Tags: html, css, json

I have a JSON file with some data.
I can populate a table without an issue, the problem is that I want to format some of the cells with a CSS file and I am stuck. Been trying several ways and none works. 
Basically how do I match the json data with each id on the html?

JavaScript

```
    var products=[];

$.getJSON('products.json',function(data){
    $.each(data.products, function(i, f){
        var tblRow = "<tr><td><img src=" + f.image_url + "></td></tr>" + "<tr><td>" + f.title + "</td></tr>" + "<tr><td>" + f.price + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.old_price + "</td></tr>"
        $(tblRow).appendTo("#list_products tbody");
    });
});
```

HTML

```
    <table id="list_products">
        <thead>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td id="prod_img"></td></tr>
            <tr><td id="title"></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="price"></td>
                <td id="price_org"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

JSON

```
    {
"products": [
    {
        "title": "Revolutionary Mini-UFO (4 pack)",
        "image_url": "https://cdn.fyndiq.se/product/fa/87/d7/d871294e94d095743c355b98b827b4a9a0/original.png",
        "old_price": "99 kr",
        "price": "69 kr",
        "price_amount": 69.00
    },
```

Comment: How many products are you writing?  In other words, what is the value of `data.products.length`?  More than 1?

Comment: Yes. Right now around 20.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Post a sample json to show what `products.json` looks like.

Comment: Updated.
Basically I want that each of the <td> has its own CSS rule. How do I add that on the JSON?

Comment: *each of the <td> has its own CSS rule*? Why? And by *CSS rule* you mean they should be uniquely addressable? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `id`, since those must be unique and you have "around 20" products.  Instead use `class`.  Just add the class names to the code that generates the HTML:

```
var tblRow = "<tr><td class='prod_img'><img src=" + f.image_url + "></td></tr>" +
    "<tr><td class='title'>" + f.title + "</td></tr>" +
    "<tr><td class='price'>" + f.price + "</td>" +
    "<td class='price_org'>" + f.old_price + "</td></tr>";
```

Demo:

```js
var products = [{
    "title": "Revolutionary Mini-UFO (4 pack)",
    "image_url": "https://cdn.fyndiq.se/product/fa/87/d7/d871294e94d095743c355b98b827b4a9a0/original.png",
    "old_price": "99 kr",
    "price": "69 kr",
    "price_amount": 69.00
}];

$.each(products, function(i, f) {
    var tblRow = "<tr><td class='prod_img'><img src=" + f.image_url + "></td></tr>" +
        "<tr><td class='title'>" + f.title + "</td></tr>" +
        "<tr><td class='price'>" + f.price + "</td>" +
        "<td class='price_org'>" + f.old_price + "</td></tr>";
    $(tblRow).appendTo("#list_products tbody");
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.prod_img img {
    max-width: 80px;
}
.title {
    font-size: 1.25em;
}
.price_org {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="list_products">
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you so much!! :)
Worked like a charm. 
(I am self-teaching JavaScript, so I do really rookie mistakes)

Answer (score 1):

To style the dynamic cells (`td`s), you should assign a `class` to them, not an `id`. To do that conditionally, you can use `if` to check if they meet a condition. Without actual json data, I cannot say more.

**Update**
If you want to be able to address the bits of data, your `tr`s each should have an `id`, and the `td`s a `class`. If you can control what json to send, I suggest you add an ID (could be a SKU) to each product and use that as an id for the rows:

JSON

```
"products": [
  {
    "id": 3812,
    "title": "Revolutionary Mini-UFO (4 pack)",
    ...
  },
  {
    "id": 7155,
    "title": ...
    ...
  }
]
```

JS

```
var rows = '';
$.getJSON('products.json',function(data){
  $.each(data.products, function(i, p){
    rows += '<tr id="product_'+p.id+'">';
    rows += '<td class="title">'+p.title+'</td>';
    rows += '... rest of tds ...';
    rows += '</tr>';
  });
  $("#list_products tbody").append(rows);
});
```